# Could not unlink

Tags: linux, perl, unlink

I'm totally puzzled with `unlink()` here:

```
my $file = "\"/home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html\"";
unlink($file) or warn "Could not unlink $file: $!";
```

will throw

```
Could not unlink "/home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html": No such file or directory
```

while the file actually exists:

```
$ ls -l "/home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 413 Mar 25 13:41 /home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html
```

*EDIT*: I also tried:

```
my $file = "/home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html";
my $file = '/home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html';
my $file = "\'/home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html\'";
```

Same error.

*EDIT2*: more tests as required by choroba

Testing the file existence with `-f` returns false.

Here's a hexdump of the real file name:

```
$ ls "/home/yasin/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html" | hexdump -c
0000000   /   h   o   m   e   /   y   a   s   i   n   /   D   o   c   u
0000010   m   e   n   t   s   /   P   r   o   g   r   a   m   m   i   n
0000020   g   /   P   e   r   l   /   e   x   t   r   a   c   t   e   d
0000030   /   P   r   u   e   b   a       c   o   n       f   o   r   m
0000040   a   t   e   o       H   T   M   L   /   m   s   g   -   2   5
0000050   7   5   -   4   .   h   t   m   l  \n                        
000005a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $file = "\"/home/.../msg-2575-4.html\"";
unlink($file)
```

is the equivalent of doing

```
rm "\"/home/.../msg-2575-4.html\""
```

Obviously, the correct shell command is

```
rm "/home/.../msg-2575-4.html"
```

so you want

```
my $file = "/home/.../msg-2575-4.html";
unlink($file)
```

or

```
my $file = '/home/.../msg-2575-4.html';
unlink($file)
```

If that second `rm` command works, so does that Perl command.

Comment: Thanks but as I already stated in the question, that also doesn't work :)

Comment: Then neither does `rm` (or `ls` if it's a file not found issue). It's not a Perl issue. Also, "don't work" is useless claim. You bother to print the error message, so why don't you give it to us.

Comment: @m0skit0, I shall repeat **If that second rm command works, so does that Perl command.** If that statement is not true, something else is different that you didn't tell us about.

Comment: Thanks for the help ikegami. I already stated what "don't work" means in the question, since I already tried what you're proposing, which is also the same than previous answer :) And yes, you're right, copy-pasting the path from the script in the `ls` or `rm` command won't work either. So this is probably due to the encoding of the folder name. I won't bother further since if I get the file name using `readdir`, `unlink` works fine.

Comment: That's not true. You only said what "doesn't work" means when you still had the buggy string.

Comment: You only have ASCII chars, so no, encoding is not an issue.

Comment: As I already said twice here, **what you're suggesting in your answer is already included in the question and I stated clearly that it does not work**: `my $file = "/home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html";
my $file = '/home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html';`. So if it's not an encoding matter, what do you think it might be? Because the path obviously exists, but when I hardcode it, it would say it doesn't exist (both Perl and the shell).

Comment: And again, you haven't stated how it doesn't work. I wish I could give you a -1 every time you refuse to say what error message you get now that you fixed the quote problem.

Comment: Huh? The error is `Could not unlink "/home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html": No such file or directory`. I don't know what you mean by *"what error message you get now that you fixed the quote problem"*.

Comment: No, that's the error with the quotes in `$file`. Did you read my answer? You need to remove those. You have no files whose name starts with `"`.

Comment: Seriously, are you kidding me? Your answer is the same as choroba's. **The error is still the same with what you're suggesting**.

Comment: No, you did not remove the quotes if the error message is `Could not unlink "/hom...`. If you removed the quotes, the error message would be `Could not unlink /hom...`. You're saying your getting the former, which means you didn't do what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: OK, yes you're right, sorry. Yes I tried that. The error is very similar. I will post it ASAP.

Comment: Use `local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($file));` and do the same with the string you build from `readdir`.

Comment: `Could not unlink /home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html: No such file or directory`. I will try with your last comment and update the question with it.

Comment: No need to post that. The problem was my fault all along. I forgot that files were generated by another script and the file names were dynamic (using timestamp) so in my tests the previous hardcoded file name did not exist anymore. Thanks for your time and your patience :)

Answer (score 4):

The filename does not contain double quotes. Do not include them in the variable's value.

```
my $file = '/home/user/Documents/Programming/Perl/extracted/Prueba con formateo HTML/msg-2575-4.html';
unlink $file or warn "Could not unlink $file: $!";
```

Comment: The quotes are because the path has spaces on it. I already tried with all kind of quotes. It does not work, same error...

Comment: @m0skit0: This is Perl, not shell. You do not need quotes for spaces.

Comment: Thanks. As I said above: same error.

Comment: @m0skit0: Can you test with `-f` that the file really exists? Can you pipe the output of `ls` to a hexdump to verify there are no other strange characters (tabs etc.)?

Comment: I've updated my question. Doesn't look like there are strange characters. Also this is a simplified test. The actual filename I'm using is returned by Perl's `readdir()`, so I guess that would return the strange characters as well, but it also fails.

Comment: @m0skit0: Can you show the actual code that fails?

Comment: The code I posted in the question fails. I mean I made this simplified test to see what was happening, and it also fails. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it, it was the quotes in the original code, although I don't know why the code posted in the question still fails.

Comment: The code posted in the question fails because it inserts double quotes into the string containing the filename - `my $file = "\"...\"";`

Comment: @DaveSherohman please see the edited question with all the tries. All those tries throw the exact same error.